# CSS property text-align being overridden by iOS Webkit for submit button

Tags: html, ios, css, webkit, text-align

The following is my CSS code for a form's submit button:

```
.submit {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    border-radius: 0rem;  
    color: rgb(63, 42, 86);
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-left: 0.05rem solid rgb(63, 42, 86);
    width: 3.6rem;
    height: 2.2rem;
    line-height: 1.75rem;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

After some initial formatting issues on iOS, I implemented `-webkit-appearance: none` which fixed most of the problems. But the "Submit" text for the Submit button is now right-aligned instead of centered on iOS, as shown in this image: http://ben-werner.com/screenshot/01.png

On the desktop version using chrome and safari however, the text displays centered as it should: http://ben-werner.com/screenshot/02.png

I don't think it is a specificity issue, as the `!important` declaration of `text-align: center` should prevent anything else in my CSS overriding it.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening on the iOS device that causes the Submit text to function differently? Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

CodePen Link: https://codepen.io/benwerner01/pen/BqErOE (Note: the html formats correctly on the CodePen site, but the same code running within safari or chrome on iOS breaks the button. I have hosted the code from CodePen at https://ben-werner.com , to demonstrate that on mobile it displays incorrectly)

Comment: Is your .submit button reliant on other css styles? If the desktop version of Chrome and safari display the text as centered, then it is most likely a media-querie issue not a webkit issue. You might have a style on mobile devices that is causing your text to get aligned right.

Comment: None of my media queries affect the .submit button, they only change width of an image. And even on desktop, when you go beneath 320px to the size of the iOS device the button doesn't break, which is why I think something weird is happening on iOS devices specifically.

Comment: Can you add your html and css to codepen or jsfiddle and send the link. This would allow us to test on our phones and use the web developer console.

Comment: I've added the code for the isolated .submit button on CodePen, and hosted it on my personal site so you can view it on your own mobile device.

Comment: Thanks for posting it to codepen! I was able to look into it and posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I know what is happening now. You are giving your submit button a specific width and height that is affecting the text-align on iOS devices. Removed the width and height values and your text will align center on iOS devices. I would also use padding to give your button the desired width and height instead of those properties.

```
.submit#mc-embedded-subscribe {
 border-radius: 0 !important;
 -webkit-appearance: none !important;
 color: rgb(63, 42, 86);
 float: right;
 border: none;
 font-size: 14px;
 border-left: 0.05rem solid rgb(63, 42, 86);
 /*     width: 3.6rem;
       height: 2.2rem; */
 text-align: center !important;
 text-align: -moz-center !important;
 text-align: -webkit-center !important;
 line-height: 1.75rem;
 transition: background-color 0.2s;
 background-color: transparent;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I set `width: none; height: none;` which did the trick.